# How to list text files in the selected directory in a listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox, directory

How can I list the text files in a certain directory (C:\Users\Ece\Documents\Testings) in a listbox of a WinForm(Windows application)?

Comment: A little note, don't subscribe this to the SelectedIndexChanged event, create a function (maybe called GetTxtFiles()) put the code in there, then have maybe a button called "Get Files", then call GetTxtFiles() from the buttons click event.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

// What directory are the files in?...

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\TestDirectory");
```

// What type of file do we want?...

```
FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
```

// Iterate through each file, displaying only the name inside the listbox...

```
foreach( FileInfo file in Files )
{
   listbox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
}
```

---

// A statement, followed by a smiley face...
That oughta do it. ;o)

Answer (score 8):

To get the txt files, try this:

```
var folder = @"C:\Users\Ece\Documents\Testings";
var txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt");

listBox.Items.AddRange(txtFiles);
```

Comment: ok to where do I write this? the program does compile but the listbox doesnt show anything

Comment: Whenever you want to get the code (maybe on a Button_Click event? for a Get Files button?

Comment: If you are going to use a button, or a method that will be allowed to be clicked multiple times you must clear the list before filling it again.

Comment: Is there any way to list only the file names and dates ?

Comment: you can ditch the need for the loop by using the listbox's AddRange method with txtfiles