# Adding folder files into a listbox

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I have searched around a lot to figure out how to add the files of a folder into listbox and I have had no luck. My goal is to click the "Browse" button on my form and have a new window pop up and let the user direct himself to a desired folder then have its contents added to the list box.

But for now all I need help with is figuring out how to add the titles of a folders files into the list box (let us say the folder is `C:\LDSS music mix\`.

Also should I use a listbox or listview?

Please help, any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Winforms? WPF? MVC? Webforms? The presentation layer you're using is likely to affect the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277222/how-to-list-text-files-in-the-selected-directory-in-a-listbox this answers my question, thanks