# Adding text files from local folder to checkedListbox in C# not triggering anything

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkedlistbox

I have created a checkedListbox in C# using visual studio. I want to populate the checkedListbox with .txt files located on my hard drive. I found a way to do that following the post below.However, when I run my program, the checkedListbox is empty. Any idea why that's happening?

[How to list text files in the selected directory in a listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277222/how-to-list-text-files-in-the-selected-directory-in-a-listbox)

## My Code:

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\John\Desktop\Test1\Test1\Test1\Data");
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work but you need to make one small change. Right now you have the code within `checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` but initially there is nothing in your `CheckedListBox` so the `SelectedIndexChanged` event will not be triggered and thus your code will not be executed; consequently, nothing will show in your `CheckedListBox`. Even if you had an item in there, why would you want to do this every time the user checks/unchecks one of the items.

Either double click your form and put that code within `Xxx_Load` (where Xxx is the name of the form) event handler or put the code within the constructor after `InitializeComponent`.

Or put the code anywhere else where it makes sense.