# How to go through xml config file and update every endpoint C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I have a software that upon installation asks for the IP address of my server and stores that address into multiple config files in different folders. Currently my code is only updating the first instance of the endpoint address inside a single file but I'm trying to have all the endpoints inside the file update to the same IP address.

Also, When a user downloads the software how would I modify the code to look where the software has been installed and then run the update IP Addresses.

What would be even more cool if someone could show me how I can update multiple IP addresses in config files inside different folders.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConfigTool
{
    class Class1
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\******\***\***\*****\*****.****.****.exe.config";
        public static IPAddress GetIPAddress(string hostName)
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            var replay = ping.Send(hostName);

            if (replay.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                return replay.Address;
            }
            return null;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc =  XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
                XElement endpoint = doc.Descendants("endpoint").FirstOrDefault();

                string address = (string)endpoint.Attribute("address");
                string newIp = "10.249.30.4";

                string pattern = "//[^:]+";
                address = Regex.Replace(address, pattern, "//" + newIp);

                endpoint.Attribute("address").SetValue(address);

            doc.Save(FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```

**XML File**

```
<endpoint name="***Local" address="net.tcp://10.249.30.4:7732/EventSubscriberServices/Secure" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="****.Services.ServiceContracts.ISubscriptionService" bindingConfiguration="TcpCustomSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="CustomValidator">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint name="***Local" address="net.tcp://10.243.32.4:7732/EventPublishServices/Secure" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="****.Services.ServiceContracts.IPublishService" bindingConfiguration="TcpCustomSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="CustomValidator">
        <identity>
          <dns value="*******" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint name="****" address="net.tcp://10.243.32.4:7732/AuthenticationServices/Secure" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="****.Services.ServiceContracts.IAuthenticationService" bindingConfiguration="TcpCustomSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="CustomValidator">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple change,  should at least solve your initial problem

```
   XDocument doc =  XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
   List<XElement> endpoints = doc.Descendants("endpoint").ToList();
   foreach (var endpoint in endpoints) {
        string address = (string)endpoint.Attribute("address");
        string newIp = "10.249.30.4";

        string pattern = "//[^:]+";
        address = Regex.Replace(address, pattern, "//" + newIp);

        endpoint.Attribute("address").SetValue(address);
    }
```

To find all files of specific type under a folder with a specific type and use then with the document load, check this answer here: [How to list text files in the selected directory in a listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277222/how-to-list-text-files-in-the-selected-directory-in-a-listbox)